# Sass Selector Sequence does not inherit `:hover` to an id.

Tags: css, sass

I am reading through this [guide](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Comments________and_____comments).

Go to section that says "Selector Sequences", it is near 3/4 of the web page, there is this codes:

```
#fake-links .link {
  @extend a;
}

a {
  color: blue;
  &:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
}
```

In the guide it says that SCSS codes will transpile into this CSS codes:

```
a, #fake-links .link {
  color: blue; }
  a:hover, #fake-links .link:hover {
    text-decoration: underline; }
```

My question: Why the `#fake-links` in third line does not become `#fake-links:hover`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because it is extending `.link` when it's a child of `#fake-links`, not extending `#fake-links` itself.

In this scenario you would have something like:

```
<div id='#fake-links'>
  <a href='#' class='link'>...</a>
</div>
```

Where as your `a` tag with the `link` class is what's styled.

If you want the `a` styles to apply to `#fake-links` you would omit `.link` from the selector in your SCSS:

```
#fake-links {
  @extend a;
}
```

As an example:

https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/2df1a3ca4d889201fe3a86e324643c04

Comment: You are right. I failed to see that there is no comma between `#fake-links` and `.link:hover`.